# How to zoom + scroll in JavaScript without flickering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web application with a zoom function that scales some absolutely positioned DIVs and also maintains the current scroll position. The zooming is animated, and the problem is that the apparent scroll position seems to flicker up and down during the animation. In other words, the boxes look like they're jumping up and down by a few pixels as the animation plays. I'd like for it to be smoother, if possible.

The problem can be seen here: http://codepen.io/excelkobayashi/pen/EKVmrK. Scroll down towards the bottom and use the +/- buttons. The flickering is worse the farther down you have scrolled. In the real application the flickering is more noticeable, probably because the DOM is more complex.

In particular, watch the top edge and the text:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fbkx1nJ.gifv]

Here is the relevant code that does the scrolling:

```
    var oldZoom = zoom;
    zoom += step;

    render();

    scrollPos = ((zoom / oldZoom) * scrollPos) || 0;
    $("#container").scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

Some notes:

- This entire block is called from an requestAnimationFrame loop to animate the zoom level changing
- step is a fraction of the difference between the current zoom and the target zoom, to create an ease-out effect.
- render is the function that resizes & moves the DIVs inside the scrollable area

```js
var zoom = 1;
var targetZoom = 1;
var lastTick = null;
var scrollPos = 0;

function render() {
  $(".main").height(1000 * zoom).each(function() {
    var pos = 10 * zoom;
    var height = 30 * zoom;
    $(this).find(".stuff").each(function() {
      $(this).css("top", pos + "px");
      $(this).css("height", height + "px");
      pos += 50 * zoom;
    });
  })

}

function animate() {
  var diff = targetZoom - zoom;
  if (!diff) {
    lastTick = null;
    return;
  }

  var tick = new Date().getTime();
  if (lastTick) {
    var minDiff = 0.01;
    var timeDiff = tick - lastTick;
    var step = diff * timeDiff / 100;

    if (diff > 0 && step <= minDiff)
      step = Math.min(minDiff, diff);
    else if (diff < 0 && step >= -minDiff)
      step = Math.max(-minDiff, diff);

    var oldZoom = zoom;
    zoom += step;

    render();

    scrollPos = ((zoom / oldZoom) * scrollPos) || 0;
    $("#container").scrollTop(scrollPos);
  }

  lastTick = tick;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function startAnimation() {
  if (lastTick)
    return;
  animate();
}

$("#zoomIn").click(function() {
  targetZoom += 0.2;
  startAnimation();
})

$("#zoomOut").click(function() {
  targetZoom -= 0.2;
  startAnimation();
})

$("#container").scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var diff = scrollPos - scrollTop;
  if (isNaN(diff) || diff < 0 || diff >= 1)
    scrollPos = scrollTop;
})

render();
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* Slow rendering (simulate complex content) */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fdd, #ddf);
}

.stuff {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Slow rendering (simulate complex content) */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, #aaa);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="zoomOut">-</button>
<button id="zoomIn">+</button>
<div id="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some notes about things I've looked into:

- The browser rounds the scrollTop value.

  - This should be accounted for since I have a separate variable storing the intended position, but it's possible this rounding is still the culprit.
  - Adding a round/floor before calling scrollTop doesn't seem to have an effect.
- CSS transform can't be used since I don't want this to affect the contents of the inner DIVs; zooming in should show more of the contents.
- Swapping the order of calling render and scrollTop doesn't change anything.
- Setting scrollTop causes a repaint, but calling render shouldn't as far as I can tell.
- Services like Google Maps handle this by zooming the previous image, then hiding it and showing the next loaded image behind it. That doesn't appear to be an option in this scenario, since this isn't image based.

Answer (score 0):

It flickers because you set the `scrollTop` value of the container with a certain step. If you want to gradually change the `scrollTop`, you might want to look at jQuery's `.animate()` function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: I would assume animate is also just setting scrollTop the same way I am, I'm not seeing why it should be any different.

Comment: You set the new (final) y value in one go, `.animate()` changes it in more steps, thus making it a little more smooth

Comment: The way I'm setting it already sets it in small increments, and does so using requestAnimationFrame, so it should be the smallest possible increments anything could be using.